# Another Latex figure numbering question

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

The following is my current code to make a list of figures:

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection-\arabic{figure}}
\listoffigures
```

My problem is that the above code numbers not as: 1-1, 1-2, 2-1, 2-2, but as 1-1, 1-2, 2-3, 2-4, 3-5, 4-6, etc. And I see that I need to change `\arabic{figure}` to something more useful. Any suggestions?

**Edit**:

Found a solution:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
```

This labels the figures 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 etc. There was some confusion to what I was asking. The other code labels 1-1, 1-2, 2-3, 2-4. The second number was not restarting the count for new sections.

Comment: Welcome to SE! What is actually your question? What you show is exactly what you require in your code.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

A solution without using any further package, just `LaTeX` core features like `\@addtoreset`

(I used the document body code from the OP and added the correct `\thefigure` definition)

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{figure}{section}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}-\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\section{section1}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{caption1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{caption1}
\end{figure}


\section{section2}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{caption3}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{caption4}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyones comment.I think it will help to have this labeled as answered for future reference to anyone looking. This is a complete answer. Replace original code with:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}

 %-----------------------------------
 % This sets up the figure numbering:
 \usepackage{chngcntr}
 \counterwithin{figure}{section}

 %---------------------------------

 \begin{document}
 \listoffigures

 \section{section1}

 \begin{figure}
    \caption{caption1}
 \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}
    \caption{caption1}
 \end{figure}


 \section{section2}

 \begin{figure}
    \caption{caption3}
 \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}
    \caption{caption4}
 \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Well, this is the same answer as the deleted one from yesterday

Comment: And it works :)

Comment: Of course it works, but it's no complete answer, in my point of view.

Comment: Define "complete."  I don't see a problem. Do you want an entire working code?

Comment: Not for me, but other, non-experienced users, will not really benefit from a `two-line` 'answer'

Comment: The proposed solution generates figure numbers of the form 1.1, 1.2, ... , 2.1, ... 3.1, etc. In your posting, in contrast, you stated that you wanted figure numbers of the form 1-1, 1-2, ..., 2-1, ..., 3-1, etc. If you want dots rather than dashes to connect the section and figure counters, you should update your original posting to reflect this revised objective.

Comment: Hint: If you do want dashes rather than dots as connectors, just provide the instruction `\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection-\arabic{figure}}` after `\counterwithin{figure}{section}`.